# Automatic eager loading?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Rather than doing something like this (which I do dozens of times across the site):

```
$posts = Post::with('user')
    ->with('image')
    ->get();
```

Is it possible to automatically call `with('image')` whenever `with('user')` is called? So in the end, I could do just:

```
$posts = Post::with('user')
    ->get();
```

And still eager load `image`?

Comment: Post::with('user','image') or write a method on Post Class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following in your model:

```
protected $with = array('image');
```

and that should do the trick.

The $**with** attribute lists relations that should be eagerly loaded with every query.

Answer (score 1):

Here another solution that works like a charm !

```
class Post extends Model {

    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = [ ... ];

    protected $hidden = array('created_at','updated_at');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function userImage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User')->with('image');
    }

}

$posts = Post::with('userImage')->get();
```

Using this you can still use your user posts `$posts = Post::with('user')->get();` whenever you don't want to make an additional call to retrieve images ..